# How do I write end() for a custom linked list container?

Tags: c++

I am writing a linked list for my homework assignment and I need to implement begin() and end() for my program's requirement.

Begin() is fairly easy

```
Node* List::begin(){return head;}
```

How should I implement end()?

Comment: Are `begin()` and `end()` supposed to return STL-style iterators, or just a `Node*`? (I doubt it's an STL-style iterator, but I thought it be best to make sure.)

Comment: The homework tag is obsolete and should no longer be used. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100.

Comment: Well I am trying to write an iterator for my linked list but I need begin() and end() first (read this somewhere online).

Comment: In STL only the last element is stored not the first one.  which points always an invalid data and this is the end(); begin() is implemented as end().next, last valid element is end().prev

Comment: @Emile Cormier Sorry, thanks for the head's up on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a `NULL` pointer, or if you have a custom `tail` node, return that.  If it's a circular doubly-linked list, you can return the sentinel node.

Keep in mind that the proper way to check for the end of the list is to call `List::end()`, so if you've properly setup your `List` class, then it doesn't exactly matter what you return, as long as

```
Node* node = mylist.begin();
while (node != mylist.end()) { /*... loop */ }
```

works and you exit the `while`-loop when you reach the end of the list.  So that main thing is that `List::end()` needs to return something *unique* that you will never encounter if you're traversing the middle of the list.

Comment: I don't have a tail, I just have a Node*next; in my Node class. How would I get to the end with just this?

Comment: Then it would be a `NULL` pointer ... in other words when `Node::next == NULL`, then you're at the end, there are no other nodes in the list.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the point in returning null. I want end() to return a pointer to the last Node in my list. Ex) Node* lastNode = list.end();

Comment: Well, that's the wrong semantics for `end()` ... as you can see, if you or anyone who utilizes your class implements a standard while-loop to iterate over your list like I've done, then you'll end-up always skipping the last node in the list.  So while you may *want* different behavior, that will not be standard behavior, and will create a lot of grief in the end.  Typically there is another `back()` method to actually return the last node in the list, and in your case, without a tail-pointer, that will have O(N) complexity as you'll have to iterate over the entire list to return it.